# Computing the cardinality of an elliptic curve group over the finite field

Tags: python, c#, sage, elliptic-curve

My objective is to get the number of points on a curve over Fp with prime p being at least 160 bit and then print it out into a textBox in Winform.

```
y^2= x^3 + Ax + B mod p
```

After some research, I stumbled upon SageMath, which I have downloaded version 9.3. However, now I'm stuck. I tried ProcessStartInfo on SageMath 9.3.lnk but it doesn't work. It threw System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception.

In short, I need to pass in this string onto SageMath 9.3 Console and then get its output in C#

```
EllipticCurve(Zmod(1032419464881212325676479338986998839248491144169), [1, 1]).cardinality()
```

I have no background knowledge about either Sage or Python. Do I have to set up the sage environment manually into a python module and then run a Python script? My Python Interpreter is 3.10.8 while SageMath uses Python 3.7.10.

Or, if this is impossible, is there any alternative way to compute it?

Edit:

```
static BigInteger P()
    {
        string arg = " -c 'EllipticCurve(Zmod(1032419464881212325676479338986998839248491144169), [1, 1]).cardinality()'";
        Process pro = new()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\SageMath 9.3\SageMath 9.3.lnk", arg)
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
        pro.Start();
        string output = pro.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        pro.WaitForExit();
        var p = BigInteger.Parse(output);
        return p;
    }
```

Comment: The algorithm exists, so you just need to write it :)

Comment: "it doesn't work" is ***not*** an error description...  i recommend taking the [Tour], as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/repl/options.html

Comment: Show the code that contains the ProcessStartInfo stuff and that generates the exception.

Comment: Are you trying to run this command: `sage -c "print(EllipticCurve(GF(1032419464881212325676479338986998839248491144169), [1,1]).cardinality())"`?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk yes, you are correct. Howerver, when I tried that in cmd. I got "'sage' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." My SAGE_ROOT is '/opt/sagemath-9.3', and my cd when running the command was "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\SageMath 9.3\runtime\opt\sagemath-9.3>"

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Windows install but SageMath might be notebook front-end. At least on the Mac, the command-line interface is just called `sage`.

Answer (score 0):

Partially solved.

I used [pari/gp system](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html) instead. [It turns out Sage can only be called through virtual machine on Windows unlike others on cmd](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/hardware-&-creative/9781849514460/3/ch03lvl1sec24/starting-sage-from-the-command-line). So all that's left for me now is to call its GP expression equivalence
`ellinit([1,1]*Mod(1,1032419464881212325676479338986998839248491144169)).no`
in Python, before Processing it in C#.